# How to access the SelectDateWidget in UpdateView?

Tags: django

How to implement something similar to SelectDateWidget in forms in class-based generic views?

For example:

```
class UserUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

    fields = ['birthday',]

    model = User

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('users:detail',
                       kwargs={'username': self.request.user.username})

    def get_object(self):

        return User.objects.get(username=self.request.user.username)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using `form_class` to do it, example:

```
# .....
from django import forms
from django.forms.widgets import SelectDateWidget


class UserUpdateForm(forms.Form):
    birthday = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget())


class UserUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = User
    fields = ['birthday',]
    form_class = UserUpdateForm
```

Comment: using both 'fields' & 'form_class' is not permitted.

Comment: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying both 'fields' and 'form_class' is not permitted.